# How can I stretch text on the canvas in with Fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I want to stretch the font of a canvas `Text` object. How can I do this?

Example (before):

[image: Before Stretch]

Example (after):

[image: And after stretch]

How could I implement this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you include some code in your question to see what you've tried?

Comment: @ventiseis i have complete this task and work on next task. thanx

Answer (score 4):

You can use scaleX to "squish" the text by scaling the text:

```
// "squish" the text to 60% of its original width
scaleX:0.60
```

**Example code and a Demo**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var myText = new fabric.Text('NEW TEXT',{
    left: 50,
    top: 60,    
});
canvas.add(myText);

var mySquishedText = new fabric.Text('NEW TEXT',{
    left: 50,
    top: 100,
    scaleX:0.60,  
});
canvas.add(mySquishedText);
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

**[Update: @AndreaBogazzi adds that `scaleX` is better handled than the matrix ops]**

Comment: better to use scaleX property. As for the same reason of the skew in the question of same days ago. transformMatrix is not really well handled.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi. I guess I'm so used to transformations that I reach for the transformation matrix first. But it sounds like you're warning me off that first instinct. So, if you could educate me, why is transformMatrix not well handled?  :-)

Comment: Actually internal functions of fabricjs does not handle the transformMatrix in a way that the control box is respected. if you try to apply a rotation transformMatrix for example you will have rotated text but still horizontal controlbox. This was considere a bug, then we just decided to decompose the transformMatrix in angle + scaleX + scaleY + skewX + translation. In future ( hope near ) the transformMatrix will be "absorbed" and represented with the basic properties that fabricjs handles ( skewX, scaleX, scaleY, angle, top and left )

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Thanks for the clarification. I'll stick to the individual transformation API commands for now :-)

Comment: would you mind adding a note the answer? people in search of fast answer rarely read comment

Comment: edited answer to use scaleX instead of transformations. :-))